# vectorize combining two matrices in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame A as follows (the numbers are totally made up)

```
ID statistic p.value
1   4           .1
2   5           .3
3   3           .4
4   2           .4
5   1           .5
6   7           .8
```

and data frame B as follows:

```
ID  Info1 Info2 ....
4    A1    B1
5    A2    B2
2    A3    ..
3    A4
1    A5
6    A6
7    A7
9    A8
8    A9
```

How would I cbind data frame A to data frame B in the correct order without a loop. I know I need to do something like:

cbind(A, B[something in here, ]) but how do I get the ordering? do I do a which statement? something else?

Comment: Are the columns in the right order in `B` as is?

Comment: Can you provide a more representative data sample and a more detailed explanation of what you are trying to do? For example - what is `Info1 == A1`? The first row of the first column of `A`? The first row of the second column of `A`?

Comment: Try `merge(A,B,by="ID")`

Comment: @iShouldUseAName: Yes, they are just random values, they can be anything.

Comment: @nrussell: I'm trying to combine two data sets. Column B has genomic data and Column A has statistical data. Info1 == A1, just means that that probe had a value of "A1" in the genomic data -- it doesn't matter what it is...

Comment: jlhoward is right, I think, you're looking for `merge`, or what in SQL would be called a join. `cbind` won't get you what you want (except in very rare circumstances with very specific data).

Comment: @joran -- awesome, how would this change if df B had the ID column as rownames rather than a separate column?

Comment: Then it would not work. The IDs need to be columns. (Keeping important information in row names is bad anyway, they should be a column.)

Comment: Couldn't you just pull the rownames into a column by df.B$ID <- rownames(df.B).

Comment: @SprengMeister: Definitely, but the matrix is large and so adding a column takes time..

Comment: If your data is so big that adding a single column is _that_ slow, you should probably start thinking about using **data.table**.

Comment: You can merge by rownames using `by` (or `by.x`/`by.y`) set to `0` or `"row.names"`.  See the help page for `merge` for more info.

Comment: @aosmith Thanks for the correction, I had forgotten about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too long for a comment.

So if I understand you correctly (from your question and all the comments), `A` and `B` are extremely large data frames. `A` has an ID column, and `B` has the `ID`s in the row names.

You should definitely use data.tables for this. Assuming you are pulling in the data from some kind of text file, read up on `fread(...)` in the data.table package. This will read the file directly into a data.table. `fread(...)` is extremely fast: 10 - 100 times faster than `read.table(...)` or `read.csv(...)` for large datasets.

Below is a comparison of the data frame approach with `merge(...)` and the data.table join approach.

**data.frame approach**

```
N <- 1e7       # 10 million rows; big enough??
set.seed(1)    # for reproducible example
A <- data.frame(ID=1:N,statistic=sample(1:10,N,replace=T),pvalue=runif(N),stringsAsFactors=F)
B <- data.frame(info1=sample(LETTERS,N,replace=T),info2=sample(letters,N,replace=T),stringsAsFactors=F)
rownames(B) <- sample(1:N,N)   # row names in randon order in B

system.time({
# this does the work...
  B$ID   <- as.integer(rownames(B))
  result <- merge(B,A,by="ID")
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#  285.75    3.15  289.33
```

**data.table approach**

```
set.seed(1)
A <- data.frame(ID=1:N,statistic=sample(1:10,N,replace=T),pvalue=runif(N),stringsAsFactors=F)
B <- data.frame(info1=sample(LETTERS,N,replace=T),info2=sample(letters,N,replace=T),stringsAsFactors=F)
rownames(B) <- sample(1:N,N)

library(data.table)
system.time({
# this does the work...
  IDs <- as.integer(rownames(B))
  setDT(A)
  setDT(B)
  B[,ID:=IDs]
  setkey(A,ID)
  setkey(B,ID)
  B[A,c("statistic","pvalue"):=list(statistic,pvalue=pvalue)]  
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#  122.46    0.40  122.87
```

So the data.table approach is twice as fast in this example. But most of the time is spent converting the rownames to a column, so if you can read them into a column to begin with, and especially if you can read the data directly into data.tables using `fread(...)`, this will be much faster.